# Possible to nest/include ioslides in another ioslides?

Tags: r-markdown

I'm working with some ioslides generated from RMarkdown using RStudio. I'd like to be able to include the rendered slides from one Rmd in another.

As of now I only know how to include the raw Rmw -- not the HTML output.

````
---
title: "Main course slides"
author: "author"
date: "November 8, 2015"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Some content

```{r child='lecture1.Rmd'}
```

```{r child='lecture2.Rmd'}
```
````

The problem with this is that it has to render each Rmd file even if it has already been compiled to HTML.

Does anyone know of a way to include the HTML output from ioslides into another ioslides directly?

Comment: Maybe with an  iframe: `<iframe src="slides.html"></iframe>` (did not test it though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I tried it and it is possible. **My solution works in Firefox**. Probably **not** in another browser (try it out) and certainly not in RStudio Viewer. 
Take the following two files `inner.Rmd` and `outer.Rmd`:

**outer.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Test"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


<style>
    #frame {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.6, 0.6); 
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        width: 1200px; 
        height: 720px;
    }

    #wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        left: 54%;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }
</style>

## R Markdown

Does nesting presentations work well?

## Slide with another presentation inside

<div id="wrapper">
<iframe id="frame" src="inner.html"></iframe>
</div>
````

**inner.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Test"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

It works!

## Yay!

Yippie!
````

I tried different approaches. Only the `iframe` method gave me what I want. Centering the inner slides though is tricky. I ended up with centering the wrapping div like

```
left: 54%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
```

Not sure why this difference of 4% is necessary. But it works:

[image]

Comment: I think this has some pretty awesome implications. Using what you have above, uou could embed a flexdashboard or storyboard in an ioslides presentation (or vice versa), correct? This would be wicked!

Comment: @Martin Schmelzer you R a rockeR!!